# Spring Security not working under Windows 7

Tags: java, jsf, spring-security

I just installed Windows 7 with NetBeans 6.5.1 and JDK 6u16. I've checked out the Web application project with SVN, which is working with Spring security. Libraries are imported, no reference problems, the same configuration worked with XP.

Here's the beginning of the exception:

```
WebModule[/db3]PWC1275: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

Full version [Here](http://codepad.org/pMZC5t1g).

Please if you have any suggestions, write below!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that Spring can't find a `DataSource` resource named "db3" that is supposed to be defined in JNDI. Are the necessary JNDI resources configured in the application server you're using?

Comment: Thanks man! Double checked / re-set the database permissions, etc. Deployed and works:) Thanks again!

Comment: Might want to edit the title / description of your problem to indicate that it actually has nothing to do with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed your operating system, chances are you also just installed your application server. Your web application depends on a database definition in the application server (JNDI). I may be wrong, but it looks like you are using GlassFish as the application server, if that is the case, you can setup a JNDI datasource from the admin console.